How can I get the value of a variable from MainActivity to another class?
I am trying to make a QR Scanner where when the application scans the QR, it will record the code number down to a
public lateinit var result

in the MainActivity.kt class. It works well, I get the result of the scan. Now the thing is, I have created a ListView class where I want to display the list of the currently scanned numbers. My problem is that whenever I try to access the variable, it doesn't show and gives me an error. I suppose calling it from the class:
MainActivity.result

doesn't work.
I am told, that it is better to make a fragment and make the list view there and access the listview as it is best to have one main activity class and pull everything there.
Is there a way to make an all accessible variable for all these classes?

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/pass-data

You can use MVVM structure for accessing variable in all classes.You can use
variable from viewmodel.Refer below link for reference.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-viewmodel-in-android/
